# Proving a math inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that if $y_0 \ne 0$ and $$|y-y_0| < \min\left(\frac{|y_0|}{2}, \ \epsilon\frac{|y_0|^2}{2}\right)$$

then $y \ne 0$ and $$\left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0}\right| < \epsilon$$

The book says the `min` notation means that,
$$|y-y_0| < \frac{|y_0|}{2}$$
and
$$|y-y_0| < \epsilon\frac{|y_0|^2}{2}$$

**I had no trouble with proving $y \ne 0$**

First, assume $y=0$

Then if $y_0 > 0$
$$|y-y_0| < \frac{|y_0|}{2}$$
$$|0-y_0| < \frac{|y_0|}{2}$$
$$1 < \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus proving $y \ne 0$

But I cannot solve the second proof.  I've tried adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing, and even squaring the equations together.  I've also tried working with them individually.

But I'm having no luck solving this problem.

Comment: Does the problem in the book actually square an absolute value? Seems redundant, at least if $y_0$ is real.

Comment: Yes, the book is squaring the absolute value.  I've also checked again to see if I wrote the equations down correctly, it is what the book reads.  The section of the book that I am on uses real numbers too, no imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle|y| = |y_0 + (y-y_0)|\geq |y_0|-|y-y_0| > |y_0| - \frac{|y_0|}{2} = \frac{|y_0|}{2}>0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\Bigl|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\Bigr| &= \frac{|y-y_0|}{|yy_0|}\\
 &< \Bigl(\epsilon \frac{|y_0|^2}{2}\Bigr)\bigg/\Bigl(\frac{|y_0|^2}{2} \Bigr)\\
 &= \epsilon
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you evaluate on how you got $|y| \ge |y_0| - |y - y_0|$?

Comment: Also, how does $|y_0| - |y-y_0| > \frac{|y_0|}{2}...$ I'm not really understanding anything on the first line.  I.e., how you got it.

Comment: @Jason Since $|a| + |b| \geq |a+b|$, then $|a|\geq |a+b|-|b|$. Let $a=y,\; b = y_0-y$ we have $|y|\geq |y_0|-|y-y_0|$.

Comment: @Jason $|y-y_0|\leq |\frac{|y_0|}{2}|$ lead to $|y_0|-|y-y_0|\geq |y_0|-|\frac{|y_0|}{2}|$